# How to Stop scroll on CollapsingToolbarLayout so it doesn't completely collapse

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

> Hi Everone could you please suggest me how to stop it .please have a look at following screenshot.

[image]

> After scrolling up it should stop below app tool bar minimum 200dp from TOP

[image]

Comment: Add multiple items under toolbar, it doesn't scrool because the item it's just one!

Comment: Could you please explain clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your request, you would like that the toolbar stopped to 200dp right?

Comment: But what have u done? Can you share the code?

Comment: Have you implemented this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height" //280dp
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/my_toolbar_bar_height" //200dp
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/> // This is place holder for content/list

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`AppBarLayout` height will be greater the `Toolbar` height (In your scenario `Toolbar` height is `200dp` so I kept `AppBarLayout` as `280dp`) Hope this is what you looking for!

Comment: Thanks a lot . Could you please avoid and remove  using hard coded value .

Comment: toolbar and appbarlayout height I am talking about .Dynamically cant we make it.

Comment: I have used them in `dimens.xml`, so it's not hard coded! I have different values in my `dimens.xml` in various values folder.

Comment: Cool .Thanks.I have not observed it.I was just checking it. but its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Set minimum collapsing height

```
android:minHeight="200dp"
```