# How to stop scroll on CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My collapsingtoolbar layout consists of an image. I want that image to be stopped scrolling before say 270dp and then only scroll the remaining content.

I had already followed 2 answers on Stackoverflow but that doesn't seems to work for me.

1. [How to Stop scroll on CollapsingToolbarLayout so it doesn't completely collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636988/how-to-stop-scroll-on-collapsingtoolbarlayout-so-it-doesnt-completely-collapse)
2. [How to Stop scroll on CollapsingToolbarLayout so it doesn't completely collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598313/stop-scroll-on-collapsingtoolbarlayout-so-it-doesnt-completely-collapse)

Layout xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_imgview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedscroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout"
            android:background="#ffff"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_shadow_height"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_shadow" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffff"
                    android:weightSum="1.0">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                        android:text="Set Wallpaper"
                        android:textColor="#ff4081"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_weight=".5"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_dw"
                        android:text="Download"
                        android:textColor="#FFFF"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="?attr/dividerHorizontal" />


                <include
                    layout="@layout/activity_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried setting the height of AppBarLayout as 280dp but it was of no use.
I'm setting image through Universal Image Loader.

Comment: Try setting the `Toolbar` `layout_height` to `280dp` instead of `?attr/actionBarSize`?

Comment: @IshitaSinha After adding layout_height no image is shown only the large toolbar is there now. 
Like this : [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/bfrp6h)

Comment: bring imageview outside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and inside the `AppBarLayout` insort try to put it between `CollapsingToolbar` and `AppBar`

Comment: @UttamPanchasara Nope, Not working. Image is above the toolbar and there is no scroll. 
[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/bfrvhk)

Comment: why you are putting `CoordinatorLayout` inside the Relative layout ???
make it parent and give the static height to imageView

Comment: @UttamPanchasara I removed the relative layout and set the height of imageView as static but still it doesn't works.

Comment: Try setting min_height property to appBarLayout to 280 dp

Comment: @Shubham Nope, not working.

Comment: Any solution here ? @JackStern